# This webpage has a redirect loop error

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect-loop

Iam getting error in browser as **'This webpage has a redirect loop'** when iam just running my url as `'http://localhost:9090/MyProj/todos/1'`

Not understanding how to fix this, please someone look into this and provide me solution.

**Below is my code:**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/todos/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %> 


<%

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("description", "Pick up Milk");
obj.put("status", "incomplete");
obj.put("id", 1);

response.setContentType("application/json");

out.print(obj);
%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

to

```
response.sendRedirect("/MyProj/index.jsp");
```

without it for example if you hit a GET on `/todo1` it will invoke Servlet which will redirect it to `/todo1/index.jsp` which will get mapped to Servlet again because this is how you mapped it, or you might just want to forward request to jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 ways to **redirect** to another Page.

1) **Send Redirect**

```
response.sendRedirect("path/index.jsp");
```

2) **Setting Header**

```
 String site = new String("http://www.google.com");
 response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
 response.setHeader("Location", site);
```

3) **Request Dispatcher**

```
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");      
    rd.forward(request, response);//method may be include or forward
```

also i have seen your servlet , you haven't override **doPost** Method in servlet. 
try to make habit of overriding both **doGet** and **doPost** method.
And write your logic in **doPost** method only.

**MyServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MyServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request,response)
}
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

}

Comment: how's any of this relevant to the problem OP is having?

Comment: @eis , i have just shown him different ways he can use for redirection.
and is in one of my way only.